# How or when is a variable updated?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, roman-numerals

I wrote this code (spoilers for LeetCode problem 13):

```
roman_numbers = [('I', 1), ('V', 5), ('X', 10), ('L', 50), ('C', 100), ('D', 500), ('M', 1000)]


class Solution:
    def get_value(self, number):
        return dict(roman_numbers)[str(number)]

    def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
        result = 0
        letter_list = list(letter for letter in s)
        for letter in s:
            try:
                if self.get_value(letter_list[0]) >= self.get_value(letter_list[1]):
                    result += self.get_value(letter_list[0])
                    letter_list.remove(letter_list[0])
                else:
                    result -= self.get_value(letter_list[0])
                    letter_list.remove(letter_list[0])
            except IndexError:
                result += self.get_value(letter_list[0])
        return result
```

The code works, but I wanted to refactor it to make it less repetitive. The pattern `self.get_value(letter_list[x])` appears many times, so I'd like to make a variable that stores a result like `letter_list.remove(letter_list[0])`, so I can write code like

```
if letter0 >= letter1:
    result += letter0
```

But **since the `letter_list` will change**, I need to make sure that the variables are updated when necessary.

I tried creating the variable inside the `for` loop, so that it updates every time through the loop:

```
for letter in s:
    letter0 = self.get_value(letter_list[0])
    letter1 = self.get_value(letter_list[1])
    ...
```

However, I'm not sure that I've properly understood what's going on.

**What exactly causes the variables to update**? Is it because the code is inside a function? Is the variable getting re-created each time through the loop?

And is this correct logic - will the variables be up-to-date when they are used? In the past I've had many problems with variable values getting out of sync.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. Variables don't change on their own. Can you show us exactly what value of a variable changes in a way that you don't expect?

Comment: Your `get_value` function  creates a new dictionary every time you call it. You might want to store your dictionary in a class variable and just access it as a normal dictionary and modify what you want.

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: "But I've always had many problems related to variables not updating" Please read [mre] and show: 1) **simple** code in which (according to your mental model) a variable is "not updating" when you think it should (try to make it so that the example code contains **everything**, and **only** what it needs in order to demonstrate the problem); 2) your explanation of **exactly** what you think should happen when the code runs if the variables "updated" according to how you think that ought to work; 3) your understanding of how the actual result appears to be different.

Comment: As it stands, it's not possible to make sense out of the problem description, because there are many things that you could mean, and because you don't appear to have a solid enough mental model in order to use the terms properly to ask the question. (If you did, you probably wouldn't have the question any more, or at least you would know the things needed in order to research the problem by yourself.)

Comment: For example, "The fact that when one loop ends the variable gets deleted just to be created again right when the next loop starts?" doesn't make any sense at all, even as a guess. At any rate, it seems like the question you are trying to ask is *not actually related to the code that you posted*, and it seems like you are *saying that the code already works* - therefore, it is *not useful to show us this code, or talk about the problem it is supposed to solve*. Please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I posted the code and explained what I would like to do to explain my mental path to arrive to the question, but now I see I simply could have asked the question "when/how exactly are variables modified?" and I guess you would have understood what I meant. 
I'm used to people (teachers mostly) not really getting my questions, as they are more of a "I created this mental map about this subject and this specific fact doesn't fit, what is wrong with my mental model?" question than just a simple question, therefore I explained my mental path. Thanks for everything!

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I guessed the variable getting deleted thing because I imagined a piece of code like -----
for _ in range(1):
    x = 'hi'.

I would read that as, one time x will have assigned a value of 'hi', and afterwards x won't mean anything (as if, it doesn't exist anymore).
In any case, you're right that I don't have a solid enough mental model of python (or programming in general)

Comment: `for` loops in Python do not create their own scope.

Comment: I edited the question. I think it's a lot clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes the variable change is the assignment operation:

```
letter0 = ...
```

Whatever is to the right of the assignment (=, += etc) is evaluated/executed first, then the result is stuffed in the variable. But no, in Python variables do not evaporate when you reach the bottom of the loop (scope) they are defined in. The next assignment simply replaces what the variable referred to before.

Answer (score 2):

So, variables are just names that refer to *objects*. You seem to expect a variable to hold an *expression* that will be dynamically executed. That's not how that works. Variables hold the *result of expressions*. If you use the following assignment statement:

```
letter0 = self.get_value(letter_list[0])
```

Then `letter0` is now referring to the object that results from evaluating the expression `self.get_value(letter_list[0])`. In this case, it is some `str` object. When you use the variable in code after that, it simply evaluates to *that string object*. It doesn't re-evaluate the expression that was used in the assignment statement: `self.get_value(letter_list[0])`.

There are two ways you might "update" a variable.

1. assign or re-assign to it.
2. you mutate the object that the variable is referring to.

Those are two different things though. Really, only (1) is *updating the variable*. The other is *mutating some object*.

Now, you should really read through the whole of Ned Batchelder's excellent [Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) (he's a StackOverflow legend). But I want to highlight one point made there: lot's of different things are assignments, not just the simple assignment

```
<some-var> = <some-expression>
```

e.g.

```
result = some_function()
```

Here are the various ways you can assign to the name `X`:

```
X = ...
for X in ...
[... for X in ...]
(... for X in ...)
{... for X in ...}
class X(...):
def X(...):
def fn(X): ... ; fn(12)
with ... as X:
except ... as X:
import X
from ... import X
import ... as X
from ... import ... as X
```

As for **mutating** an object, that is generally done through some *mutator method*, e.g.:

```
my_object.mutator_method(some_arg)
```

For example, here are two different mutator methods being called on the same object through the variable `mylist`:

```
mylist.append(42)
mylist.pop()
```

Note, operators and various other language constructs can also mutate an object because underneath the hood, the end up calling a mutator method!

```
mylist += [42]  # This one actually is an assignment too!
mylist[i] = 42  # This one is *not an assignment*!
```

Watch out with that last one! It's actually *not an assignment*!

Comment: I don't expect it, rather I'd very much want it to be possible :). But I'm like a kid saying "if there's not enough money, print more", meaning I see that immediate-term solution but I have no idea whatsoever about the consequences it could have.
I'll take a look at the website you posted, it sure will help me a lot :)